# How to embed all the Youtube channel-videos into website..?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channels

I work on a site, I want to embed all the Youtube-channel-videos into my site.

I found similar post like this code that acutally worked fine and loaded all videos as desired for some time, but yesterday I saw that the channel-video-list didnt load, displaying only one video. What have happend? Has Youtube made any updates lately so the channel-videos wont load?

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=FeetMinistries" width="100%" height="800"></iframe>
```

Thanks for all the help I can get.
André

Answer (score 0):

you could try

Embed a video

> - On a computer, go to the YouTube video you want to embed.
> - Under the video, click SHARE Share.
> - Click Embed.
> - From the box that appears, copy the HTML code.
> - Paste the code into your blog or website HTML.

Embed a playlist

- Sign in to your YouTube account on a computer.
- On the left side of the page, select the playlist you want to embed.
- Copy the playlist ID from the URL.
- Modify the embed code for an individual video by doing the following:
- In the place of the video ID (after "embed/"), substitute
  "videoseries?list=".
- Then paste the playlist ID after the "=".
- Paste the code into your blog or website HTML.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Consider following JQuery code snippet I'm usually using to dynamically load channel by channel Id.

```
$.ajax({
                            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists",
                            type: 'get',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: {
                                        part : 'snippet', 
                                        channelId: <channel_id>,
                                        maxResults : 50,
                                        key: '<API Key>', 
                                    },
                            success:    function(data) {
                                        }
                  });
```

Comment: Can you put that JQuery code directly into html without futher coding...?